# Arranging “success” such that 2 “s” come together when (i) all “s” are identical (ii) all “s” are distinct

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many ways can the letters of the word "success" be arranged such that two "s" come next together ($3$ ”s” formation is allowed) if (i) all s -es are identical (ii) if all s -es are distinct (for eg, s1,s2,s3)

**My solutions :**

For (i) As all s -es are identical, we don’t need to worry about the arrangement, so the answer would be $6!/2! - 5!/2!$, which is equal to $300$. The according equation is formed because there will be repetitions in $3$ “s” formations, for example (ss)s = s(ss).

For (ii), when they are distinct, they will permute themselves inside the groups, so my answer would be $(6!/2! \times 2! \times 3) - (5!/2! \times 3!)$, which is equal to $360$. Edit- I meant by [(6!/2!) x 2! x 3] - [(5!/2!) x 3!] (=1800). My bad.
I still did the minus because (s1s2)s3 would equal to s1(s2s3).

However, I am not confident about my answers, so I would be so grateful if I can get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first answer is correct, but the second is too small.

(i) Let's verify your answer with a different method.

We will subtract the number of arrangements of the letters of the word $SUCCESS$ with no adjacent $S$s from the total number of arrangements.

The word $SUCCESS$ contains seven letters, so we have seven positions to fill.  We can fill three of them with $S$s in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways, two of the remaining four positions with $C$s in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, then arrange the distinct letters $U$ and $E$ in the remaining two positions in $2!$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}2!$$
arrangements of the letters of the word $SUCCESS$.

To count the number of arrangements with no consecutive $S$s, we first arrange the four letters $C, C, E, U$.  There are four positions to fill.  We can fill two of them with $C$s in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, then arrange the distinct letters $U$ and $E$ in the remaining two positions in $2!$ ways.  This creates five spaces in which to place the $S$s, three between successive letters in the arrangement of $C, C, E, U$ and two at the ends of the row.  $$\square L_1 \square L_2 \square L_3 \square L_4 \square$$
where the $L$s represent the letters $U, E, C, C$ and the squares represent the spaces where we can place an $S$.  To ensure that no two $S$s are consecutive, we choose three of these five spaces in which to place an $S$, which can be done in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways.  Thus, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}2!\binom{5}{3}$$
arrangements of the letters of the word $SUCCESS$ in which no two of the $S$s are adjacent.

Thus, the number of arrangements of the letters of the word $SUCCESS$ in which at least two $S$s are adjacent is
$$\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}2! - \binom{4}{2}2!\binom{5}{3} = 300$$
as you found.

(ii) If the $S$s are distinct, then we must arrange the letters
$$S_1, S_2, S_3, C, C, E, U$$
so that no two of the $S$s are adjacent.

If there were no restrictions, we could choose two of the seven positions for the $C$s, then arrange the five distinct letters $U, E, S_1, S_2, S_3$ in $5!$ ways, giving
$$\binom{7}{2}5!$$
possible arrangements.

From these, we subtract those with at least two adjacent $S$s.  We can first arrange the four letters $C, C, E, U$, which can be done in $\binom{4}{2}2!$ ways since we must choose two of the four positions for the $C$s, then arrange the distinct letters $U$ and $E$ in the remaining two positions.  This creates five spaces in which to place the $S$s.
$$\square L_1 \square L_2 \square L_3 \square L_4 \square$$
where the $L$s represent the letters $C, C, E, U$ and the squares represent the spaces where we can place an $S$.  To ensure that no two $S$s are consecutive, we choose three of these five spaces in which to place an $S$, which can be done in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways.  The three distinct $S$s can be arranged in the selected spaces in $3!$ ways.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}2!\binom{5}{3}3!$$
arrangements in which no two Ss are adjacent.

Therefore, there are
$$\binom{7}{2}5! - \binom{4}{2}2!\binom{5}{3}3! = 1800$$
arrangements in which at least two $S$ are adjacent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and explanation. And funnily, when I rechecked my answer, I was trying to write [(6!/2!) x 2! x 3] - [(5!/2!) x 3!] which is also equal to 1800. And I misunderstood myself xD. Anyway, thank you so much for your detailed explanation.